# Assert statement with if/else condition on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to convert below Python function to TF graph compatible function:

```
def check_func(x):
    if len(x.shape) == 1:
        return

    if len(x.shape) == 2:
        if x.shape[1] == 1:
            return

    raise ValueError("Wrong shape")
```

This is my unsuccessful attempt:

```
@tf.function
def check_func(x):
    tf.debugging.Assert(tf.rank(x) == 1 or (tf.rank(x) == 2 and tf.shape(x)[1] == 1), [x])
```

I got following error:

```
E             ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for '{{node cond/cond/strided_slice}} = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1](cond/cond/Shape, cond/cond/strided_slice/stack, cond/cond/strided_slice/stack_1, cond/cond/strided_slice/stack_2)' with input shapes: [1], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <1>, input[2] = <2>, input[3] = <1>.
```

I guess it's because the input I'm passing only has rank of 1 and somehow it falls into the second condition? Can anyone please help? Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using elif?

Comment: How would it work under TF graph computation? I guess I need to use tf.cond (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond)?

Comment: I was talking about your first function check_func, although tf.cond might work (never used it myself though)

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes we can technically use if/else, no specific reason.